# php to mysql update query isnt running properly

Tags: php, mysql

UPDATE

I can now get it to update with actual values by having the coding on one page instead of 2 but it still wont update using the form, I have made it to only work on the landline for now until I can get it to work from the form.

Below is the new code without the html body which has some links to the php header;

```
    $search = $_POST['search']; 
$search2 = $_POST['search2'];

$results = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT RecordReference, Dateofrecordcreation, Status, AgentName, ReturnFiledOn, InfoOnline, Surname, Forename, DateofBirth, UTR, NINO, Address, Postcode, AddressAffectiveFrom, Mobile, Landline, Email, Balance FROM `selfemployed` WHERE Surname LIKE '$search' AND Forename LIKE '$search2'"); 



while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
$RecordReference = $row['RecordReference'];
$Dateofrecordcreation = $row['Dateofrecordcreation'];
$Status = $row['Status'];
$AgentName = $row['AgentName'];
$ReturnFiledOn = $row['ReturnFiledOn'];
$InfoOnline = $row['InfoOnline'];
$Surname = $row['Surname'];
$Forename = $row['Forename'];
$DateofBirth = $row['DateofBirth'];
$UTR = $row['UTR'];
$NINO = $row['NINO'];
$Address = $row['Address'];
$Postcode = $row['Postcode'];
$AddressAffectiveFrom = $row['AddressAffectiveFrom'];
$Mobile = $row['Mobile'];
$Landline = $row['Landline'];
$Email = $row['Email'];
$Balance = $row['Balance'];
}

if(isset($_POST['Update']))

$RecRef = $_POST['RecordReference'];
$Datereccr = $_POST['Dateofrecordcreation'];
$Sta = $POST['Status'];
$AgName = $_POST['AgentName'];
$Srnm = $_POST['Surname'];
$Frnm = $_POST['Forename'];
$DoB = $_POST['DateofBirth'];
$NatIn = $_POST['NINO'];
$Add = $_POST['Address'];
$Pstc = $_POST['Postcode'];
$AddAffFrm = $_POST['AddressAffectiveFrom'];
$UTaxR = $_POST['UTR'];
$Mob = $_POST['Mobile'];
$llffs = $_POST['Landline'];
$Eml = $_POST['Email'];
$RetFiled = $_POST['ReturnFiledOn'];
$Bal = $_POST['Balance'];
$Online = $_POST['InfoOnline'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

// Information to update
    $sql_query = "UPDATE `selfemployed` SET `Landline` = '$llffs' WHERE RecordReference = '$RecordReference'";
// Update Qquery
    mysqli_query($connection, $sql_query);

// Close our connection to the database
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
```

Original post

I have been trying to create an update function for my database and have been stuck for days on this now so thought that I would ask for help. The code seems to run without issues and no errors are being reported but it isn't being updated.

The search/display code is below (this works ok except it doesnt show all the text when there is spaces in the data)

Here is the search and display code

```
require_once "config.php";

$search = $_POST['search']; 
$search2 = $_POST['search2'];

$results = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT RecordReference, Status, ReturnFiledOn, InfoOnline, Surname, Forename, DateofBirth, UTR, NINO, Address, Postcode, AddressAffectiveFrom, Mobile, Landline, Email, Balance FROM `selfemployed` WHERE Surname LIKE '$search' AND Forename LIKE '$search2'"); 



while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
$RecordReference = $row['RecordReference'];
$Dateofrecordcreation = ['Dateofrecordcreation'];
$Status = $row['Status'];
$AgentName = $row['AgentName'];
$ReturnFiledOn = $row['ReturnFiledOn'];
$InfoOnline = $row['InfoOnline'];
$Surname = $row['Surname'];
$Forename = $row['Forename'];
$DateofBirth = $row['DateofBirth'];
$UTR = $row['UTR'];
$NINO = $row['NINO'];
$Address = $row['Address'];
$Postcode = $row['Postcode'];
$AddressAffectiveFrom = $row['AddressAffectiveFrom'];
$Mobile = $row['Mobile'];
$Landline = $row['Landline'];
$Email = $row['Email'];
$Balance = $row['Balance'];
}

// Close our connection to the database
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {color: #000000}
.style10 {color: #F4A5A4}
.style11 {color: #D3D3D3}
.style14 {color: #000000; font-size: 14px; }
.style15 {font-size: 14px}
.style16 {color: #D3D3D3; font-size: 14px; }
.style17 {color: #F4F2A4; font-size: 14px; }
.style3 {color: #000000; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; }
.style8 {color: #ABDEB2}
.style9 {color: #F4F2A4}
.style18 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
-->
</style>
<body>
<form action="updateselfemp.php" method="post">
  <table width="850" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="420" valign="top" bgcolor="#F4A5A4"><table width="418" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td align="right">Reference<span class="style10">::</span></td>
          <td><label>
          <input name="RecordReference" type="text" id="RecordReference" value=<?php echo $RecordReference; ?> >
          </label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">Date of Record Creation<span class="style10">::</span></td>
          <td><label>
            <input type="text" name="Dateofrecordcreation" id="Dateofrecordcreation" value=<?php echo $Dateofrecordcreation; ?> >
          </label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="222" align="right"><span class="style15"><span class="style14">Company Status<span class="style10">:</span></span></span></td>
          <td width="186"><select name="Status" id="Status">
            <option selected><?php echo $Status; ?></option>
            <option value="ACTIVE">ACTIVE</option>
            <option value="CLOSED">CLOSED</option>
            <option value="DORMANT">DORMANT</option>
            <option value="PHOENIX">PHOENIX</option>
            <option value="NO LONGER A CUSTOMER">NO LONGER A CUSTOMER</option>
          </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><span class="style14">Agent Name<span class="style10">:</span>:</span></td>
          <td><label>
          <input name="AgentName" type="text" id="AgentName" value=<?php echo $AgentName; ?> >
          </label></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
      <span class="style1"></span></td>
      <td width="420" valign="top" bgcolor="#F4F2A4"><p class="style3">Return Details</p>
          <table width="418" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td width="263" align="right"><span class="style14">Date Return Filed</span><span class="style17">::</span></td>
              <td width="145"><label>
              <input name="DateReturnFiled" type="text" id="DateReturnFiled" value=<?php echo $ReturnFiledOn; ?> >
              </label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right"><span class="style15"><span class="style1">Is this information online?</span><span class="style9">::</span></span></td>
              <td><label>
              <select name="Online" id="Online">
                  <option><?php echo $InfoOnline; ?></option>
                  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                  <option value="No">No</option>
                  <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                </select>
              </label></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" bgcolor="#D3D3D3"><p class="style3">Details</p>
          <table width="418" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td width="268" align="right"><span class="style14">Surname</span><span class="style16">::</span></td>
              <td width="140"><label>
                <input name="Surname" type="text" id="Surname" value=<?php echo $Surname; ?> >
              </label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right"><span class="style15"><span class="style1">Forename</span><span class="style11">::</span></span></td>
              <td><label>
                <input name="Forename" type="text" id="Forename" value=<?php echo $Forename; ?> >
              </label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right"><span class="style15"><span class="style1">Date of Birth</span><span class="style11">::</span></span></td>
              <td><label>
              <input name="DateofBirth" type="text" id="DateofBirth" value=<?php echo $DateofBirth; ?> >
              </label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right"><span class="style15"><span class="style1">UTR</span><span class="style11">::</span></span></td>
              <td><label>
              <input name="UTR" type="text" id="UTR" value=<?php echo $UTR; ?> >
               </label></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right"><span class="style15"><span class="style1">National Insurance No</span><span class="style11"></span></span></td>
              <td><label>
              <input name="NINO" type="text" id="NINO" value=<?php echo $NINO; ?> >
              </label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right" valign="top"><span class="style15"><span class="style1">Address<span class="style11">::</span></span></span></td>
              <td><label>
                <textarea name="Address" id="Address" cols="25" value=<?php echo $Address; ?> rows="3"></textarea>
              </label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right" valign="top"><span class="style15"><span class="style1">Postcode</span><span class="style11">::</span></span></td>
              <td><label>
                <input name="Postcode" type="text" id="Postcode" value=<?php echo $Postcode; ?> >
              </label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right" valign="top"><span class="style15"><span class="style1">Address Affective From</span><span class="style11">::</span></span></td>
              <td><input name="AddressAffectiveFrom" type="text" id="AddressAffectiveFrom" value=<?php echo $AddressAffectiveFrom; ?> ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right" valign="top"><span class="style15"><span class="style1">Mobile</span><span class="style11">::</span></span></td>
              <td><label>
                <input name="Mobile" type="text" id="Mobile" value=<?php echo $Mobile; ?> >
              </label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right"><span class="style15"><span class="style1">Landline</span><span class="style11">::</span></span></td>
              <td><label>
                <input name="Landline" type="text" id="Landline" value="<?php echo $Landline; ?>" >
              </label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right"><span class="style15"><span class="style1">Email</span><span class="style11">::</span></span></td>
              <td><label>
                <input name="Email" type="text" id="Email" value=<?php echo $Email; ?> >
              </label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
              <td><label></label></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td>
      <td valign="top" bgcolor="#ABDEB2"><p class="style3">Balance</p>
          <table width="418" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td width="261" align="right"><span class="style14">Outstanding Balance<span class="style8">::</span></span></td>
              <td width="147"><label>
              <input name="Balance" type="text" id="Balance" value=<?php echo $Balance; ?> >
              </label></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        <p class="style1">&nbsp;</p>
        <p class="style1">&nbsp;</p>
        <p class="style1">&nbsp;</p>
        <p class="style1">&nbsp;</p>
        <p class="style1">&nbsp;</p>
        <p class="style1">&nbsp;</p>
        <p class="style1">&nbsp;</p>
        <p class="style1">&nbsp;</p>
        <p class="style1">&nbsp;</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="right"><label>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Update" value="Update Record">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value"<?php echo $RecordReference; ?>">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<span class="style18">Current File Content</span>
<table>
            <tr><td>Record Reference</td> <td><?php echo $RecordReference; ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Date of Record Creation</td> <td><?php echo $Dateofrecordcreation; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Status</td> <td><?php echo $Status; ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Agent Name</td> <td><?php echo $AgentName; ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Return Filed On</td> <td><?php echo $ReturnFiledOn; ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Surname</td> <td><?php echo $Surname; ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Forename</td> <td><?php echo $Forename; ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Date of Birth</td> <td><?php echo $DateofBirth; ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>UTR</td> <td><?php echo $UTR; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>NINO</td> <td><?php echo $NINO; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Address</td> <td><?php echo $Address; ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Postcode</td> <td><?php echo $Postcode; ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>AddressAffectiveFrom</td> <td><?php echo $AddressAffectiveFrom; ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Mobile</td> <td><?php echo $Mobile; ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Landline</td> <td><?php echo $Landline; ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Email</td> <td><?php echo $Email; ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Balance</td> <td><?php echo $Balance; ?></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the update code

```
<?php
$RecordReference = $_POST['RecordReference'];
$date = date('d/m/Y h:i:s', time());
$Status = $_POST['Status'];
$AgentName = $_POST['AgentName'];
$ReturnFiledOn = $_POST['DateReturnFiled'];
$InfoOnline = $_POST['Online'];
$Surname = $_POST['Surname'];
$Forename =$_POST['Forename'];
$DateofBirth = $_POST['DateofBirth'];
$UTR = $_POST['UTR'];
$NINO = $_POST['NINO'];
$Address = $_POST['Address'];
$Postcode = $_POST['Postcode'];
$AddressAffectiveFrom = $_POST['AddressAffectiveFrom'];
$Mobile = $_POST['Mobile'];
$Landline = $_POST['Landline'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Balance = $_POST['Balance'];
// Connect to the database

require_once "config.php";

// update data in mysqli database 
$sql = ("UPDATE selfemployed SET RecordReference = '$RecordReference', Dateofrecordcreation = '$date', Status = '$Status', AgentName = '$AgentName', ReturnFiledOn = '$ReturnFiledOn', InfoOnline = '$InfoOnline', Surname = '$Surname', Forename = '$Forename', DateofBirth = '$DateofBirth', UTR = '$UTR', NINO = '$NINO', Address = '$Address', Postcode = '$Postcode', AddressAffectiveFrom = '$AddressAffectiveFrom', Mobile = '$Mobile', Landline = '$Landline', Email = '$Email', Balance = '$Balance' WHERE RecordReference = '$RecordReference'");

// Close our connection to the database
mysqli_close($connection);
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
window.history.go(-2);
</script>
```

Any help with this is very much appreciated as I am at a loss as to what is wrong.

Comment: Hey! Please try to only show us the relevant code, so no html and css for example

Comment: You never execute the update query please add `$run= mysqli_query($connection,$sql)` then you should be sorted

Comment: What is the problem? Do you have an error?

Comment: in future never ever again post your database login details online

Comment: The most important step for now is to change your DB login credentials. Not only have you shared them online, several people have pointed it out. Just editing the current post is not enough; some people here can still see the original post.

Comment: Please for your server safety, remove the real user/db/host/pass in your update code.

Comment: Delete this question,repost it without credentials.

Comment: @Mihai. That's too late. He has to change those credentials NOW!

Comment: Ben Hillier, thank you for your advice and thoughts, I have altered the login details on the code to avoid sharing the actual login.

Comment: I have changed the file now to have the following line of code instead of the login details 'require_once "config.php";
'

Comment: I have tried removing the form input for each column of the row, replacing it with the data (name for name column etc) and this doesnt work so it doesnt seem to be an issue with the data, the code runs without bringing up error codes which makes me wonder if the error is on the server side, is there server settings with phpmyadmin that can block data?

Answer (score 0):

```
// update data in mysqli database 
$sql = "UPDATE selfemployed SET RecordReference = '$RecordReference', Dateofrecordcreation = '$date', Status = '$Status', AgentName = '$AgentName', ReturnFiledOn = '$ReturnFiledOn', InfoOnline = '$InfoOnline', Surname = '$Surname', Forename = '$Forename', DateofBirth = '$DateofBirth', UTR = '$UTR', NINO = '$NINO', Address = '$Address', Postcode = '$Postcode', AddressAffectiveFrom = '$AddressAffectiveFrom', Mobile = '$Mobile', Landline = '$Landline', Email = '$Email', Balance = '$Balance' WHERE RecordReference = '$RecordReference'";
//Send query
mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

// Close our connection to the database
mysqli_close($connection);
```

Please try to use Prepared Statements (mysqli stmts or PDOs) to avoid SQL Injections.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Perhaps you should explain why, if you believe that.

Comment: Sorry my fault. Forgot a parameter first.

Comment: @BenHillier the initial answer before edit `mysqli_query()` had a single parameter

Comment: I have tried the code above and chnged sql to $sql but it didnt work

Comment: no, it runs through everything but just doesnt update the data

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that when I put everything on one page all I needed to do was change the update button ID and Name from Update to update it then worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

You never run update query please run update query like below

```
$sql = "UPDATE selfemployed SET RecordReference = '$RecordReference', Dateofrecordcreation = '$date', Status = '$Status', AgentName = '$AgentName', ReturnFiledOn = '$ReturnFiledOn', InfoOnline = '$InfoOnline', Surname = '$Surname', Forename = '$Forename', DateofBirth = '$DateofBirth', UTR = '$UTR', NINO = '$NINO', Address = '$Address', Postcode = '$Postcode', AddressAffectiveFrom = '$AddressAffectiveFrom', Mobile = '$Mobile', Landline = '$Landline', Email = '$Email', Balance = '$Balance' WHERE RecordReference = '$RecordReference'";
// Update Qquery
mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

// Close our connection to the database
mysqli_close($connection);
```

Comment: No joy I am affraid

Comment: can you tell me exact error you getting for show error try like this mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

Comment: There is no error, the code runs and returns to the original page (2 steps back) but the update does not apply, so for example - Telephone is blank so I enter a number into the telephone box, press submit and the code runs and redirects me to the dashboard but when I check the entry using the search function it brings up the original data without any changes, the changes also don't show on the database either. I can manually update the database but my client cant keep logging in to do this, they need to be able to do it with a query.

Comment: @ Mukesh Jakhar I tried updating just the landline with a fixed value (00000000000 instead of $_POST['Landline'];) it worked once but then wouldn't work with the post function or again as a fixed value on one or all of the columns, its seems to me like there is an issue on the server, would you agree?

Comment: The database is PHPMyAdmin if that helps figure out the problem.